# What is the following concept in C Bit wise oprerator? It optimised my code and reduced its running time drastically

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
for(idx = 63; idx >= 0; idx--){ 
   if((num & (1ll<<idx)) != 0) 
       return 1ll << idx;
}
```

It optimized my code drastically. Earlier I had the code given below. Can anyone help me with the reason for that drastic change?

```
int i,j;
for(i=63;i>=0;i--){ 
   if(num & (1<<i)){ 
        break; 
   } 
} 
num &= 0; 
num |= (1<<i); 
return num;
```

Comment: Compare the generated assembly instructions for both variants and you will see. You should also compare the two variants with different levels of compiler optimizations.

Comment: The only difference I see is obvious: instead of `num &= 0; num |= (1<<i);` which is actually the same as `num = (1 << i)`, the first code fragment returns `(1 << i)`

Comment: What is the mysterious entity referred to as "it" that optimized your code?

Comment: Do you compile with optimization enabled ? Did you verify that your old implementation was correct ? `1<<i` isn't correct unless `int` on your platform is 64 bit.

Comment: The second one is wrong. After the loop, i *can* be -1, so `num |= (1<<i);` is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main differences.
The first is that in  the original code you had a bug.
Basically what you are doing here is looking for the highest set bit in a 64 bit number.
When you were running 1 << i you would always get a zero until i is below 32. When you changed it to be 1ll it was casted to a long long and thus a 1ll << i would  produce a number other than 0 for i > 32.
The second difference is the saved & and shift when returning the number.

BTW you can do the whole thing without a while loop (at least with GCC). Just do:

```
return 1ll << (64 - __builtin_clzll(num))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your previous code,

```
num &= 0; 
num |= (1<<i);
```

requires additional computation compared to first logic where you just return if in case your `if` statement successful. Disassembly both the code snippets should give you the complexity added in the later one.

Comment: Yes @SunEric I perfectly understood your point of additional computation incurred in the earlier implementation. I got the concept now. Thank you so much.